# Displaying PDF in Cordova app browser

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, cordovawebview

We have a Cordova app built for iPad which opens a .pdf file in the native webview using inappbrowser plugin.

We want to port this app to the Windows 8 Surface, but the inappbrowser in Windows 8 does not open the .pdf file in the browser.

Is there any way we can open the .pdf file in browser in Windows 8 Surface?

We have tried adding an iframe but it could not open the .pdf file.

Comment: I rewrote the title to be clearer and shorter, and rewrote the body to clarify that as well.

Comment: There is no inbuilt PDF viewer for WinRT. You can use the `PdfDocument` and `PdfPage` available in Windows 8.1 to convert the *.pdf file into a set of images, see the accepted answer [in this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585996/windows-store-app-display-pdf)

Comment: Is there a way to open online xls , txt , ppt , jpg , pdf file format in windows 8 cordova app within the application and not launch the file in another app.